# Why Google uses weird CSS class names?

Tags: css

When I inspect element let's say Google+ homepage I can see that Google uses weird CSS
css class names (eg .o-B-Ra fq-Ra) is there any benefits from naming classes like that, or they are named automatically by a third party program?

Thanks.

Comment: when you're serving up as much data as google is, cutting a css class from (say) `current` to just `c` will save a mindboggling amount of bandwidth.

Comment: Hands up, thanks for informing me. I searched alot before posting, couldn't find it. Thanks Neal.